# Correct command line parameters for gcc compilation of SDL

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, sdl, codeblocks

I recently started SDL2.0 programming.
I did a lot of researches and i tried all but i still get those "undefined reference" errors for all the SDL functions:

```
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'|
undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'|
undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

on that simple test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nUnable to initialize SDL:  %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
  }
  atexit(SDL_Quit);

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

If i have to guess the problem occurs due to the wrong command line syntax.
In this case what should be the correct one?

Comment: have you looked this link http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_SDL_with_Code::Blocks?

Comment: @Jayesh I just did. It continues with the same errors.
Maybe its my english and the understanding of some weird terms.
I doubt such links can actually help me :(

Comment: can you give your linker settings?

Comment: @Jayesh

Only `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
I cleared them before a while.

Comment: I mean as show your compiler settings, can you show linker settings. Also i think this will use `WinMain` as entry point and you have given `main` as entry point. Look for more setup here http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php

Comment: @Jayesh there, i uploaded a screenshot to my webhost:
http://vegasoft.site90.com/PICTURE_38%20ESSENCE-PC.bmp

Comment: gcc main.o  \`sdl-config --libs\` -o main

Comment: @Edenia And also add `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`. i assume you have give source path in `search directories` tab.

Comment: Current linker options:
http://vegasoft.site90.com/PICTURE_39%20ESSENCE-PC.bmp
Still with the errors though.

Comment: @Edenia Are you sure you not linked the program to the 64-bit version of SDL while compiling for 32-bit?

Comment: @Jayesh I am not sure. I link to w/e i saw from the tutorials.

Comment: Soo.. how to find/fix the difference in case i do it wrong?

Comment: @Edenia For which function you get errors? can you post exact errors also here?

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/codeblocks/

Comment: Try putiing the -mwindows flag

Comment: In either ways. It won't build it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't linking to the SDL libraries correctly.

Add the following lines int Other Linker Option

```
-lSDL -lSDLmain
mingw32
SDLmain
SDL
```

Also  You need to check setup for how to compile SDL in codeblock

[http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_SDL_with_Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_SDL_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks)
http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/codeblocks/

If it's not too late then try from the beginging to how to set up SDL in codeblock and successfully run it? Below link provide you exact steps for it.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57275-setting-up-codeblocks-to-work-with-sdl/

Comment: Uh.. maybe it is too late. I did all that. I tried everything.
I got provided by 5 different tutorials i have no horrific clue which one to pick up. Some are not relative to SDL 2.0, others don't describe everything, different ways... its messed up.

Comment: If you have some time, maybe you can take a look via Team Viewer? That would be greatful.

Comment: might be something weird. :x

Comment: @Edenia have you used skype?

Comment: @Edenia psp-gen? is it your skype name?

Comment: Skype ID: psp-gen
skype name: Al3

You would rather find me on the skype id.

Comment: @Edenia Ok found it. Accept requst

Answer (score 0):

You might have not linked SDL2 correctly to your CodeBlocks project and not referred to SDL2 correctly in your code.

**1:**
Go to "Linker options" in "Build Options" menu and make sure you have added these library's to your project like this:
[Library's to include in linker options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlLlr.png)

Importent!: save project before running it after adding/changeing library's.

**2:**
Change:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

to this:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

if you still encounter problems compiling and running it, it's most likely either, your SDL2 files not placed correctly in the compiler's folders, or your using an version of gcc with some missing tools.

These Youtube video's explain everything in great detail:

1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0LUf7Ibpi0

2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtUw_7CvRRo